# Cursor keys leave insert mode in irb in vi mode

Tags: vim, ruby, readline

I am using vi-mode in a ruby IRB by having a ~/.inputrc containing only the following line:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Since I changed from ruby 1.8.7-p371 to ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0, IRB (and the rails console) started behaving differently.

Before I could use the left and right cursor arrow keys in insert mode and the cursor would move accordingly, staying in insert mode (like standard in vim).

Typing arrow left now deletes all characters till the end of the line and takes me right out of insert mode.
I am lost, why is this happening? And, more importantly: How can I get IRB to interpret the arrow keys as such (and not, as is probably the case, as escape sequences)?

I am using MacOSX 10.8.5.

#### Update:

I installed readline like this:

```
brew install readline
brew link readline
```

and the version installed is 6.2.4.

Comment: How did you install the readlines package?  Also, is that your only setting in your ~/.inputrc file?

Comment: And you state that you moved to 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 but from what?  What was working for you previously?  Also what version of Readlines package are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889818/485864 mentions the version.  That answer may help.  It is going from 1.8 to 1.9 in a similar fashion.  Those versions are earlier, but maybe the additional package is needed.  And yes, Ruby may need to be recompiled after updating those.